# ToolStripItems not Showing Up

Tags: vb.net

To make it short, I've developed an application and at its final stages I thought about creating a form for the first run of the application, where the user (admin) will set up some control variables.

In order to achieve this functionality, I had to make sure that there was a form that would control if the user was 'seeing' the application for the first time or not, calling it a ghost form (this form won't be visible).

This 'ghost' form will check if the variable FirstRun is true or not. If it's true, a form to set up the control variables will be called, otherwise the main form of the application will be launched:

```
Public Class fGhostForm

    Private Sub fGhostForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub fGhostForm_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosed
        If My.Settings.FirstRun Then
            Dim FormToLaunch As fFirstRunApplicationSettings = New fFirstRunApplicationSettings()
            FormToLaunch.ShowDialog()
        Else
            Dim FormToLaunch As fMainForm = New fMainForm()
            FormToLaunch.ShowDialog()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

This works fine and dandy as I can see my main form on its primary state, meaning that I'm currently a guest user that currently has almost no access to any functionality of the application.
In order to get access, I need to first log in into my database and I do that by clicking the option "Iniciar Sessão" and a new form pops up where the user must input his credentials:

[2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GoHD.png)

After the login, according to which level of security the user has, new toolstripitems must appear on the menustrip of the main form.
Now here's the problem:

If I set the "fMainForm" to be the startup form for the project, this is the scenario that occurs.
However, if I set the "fGhostForm" to be the startup form, I do get to see the main form popping up, but after the login, the toolstripitems do not show up at all.

To isolate the problem, I decided to create a test button, just to create a new instance of the main form, calling an exact copy of it.
Now, when I perform the login step, on the main form that was called from pressing the test button, the toolstripitems do not show up.
However, on the first main form, the toolstripitems do show up as their supposed to (I did this with the "fMainForm" as the startup form for the project):

[3.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1eTQ.png)

[4.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EBjv.png)

[5.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f18co.png)

[6.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2vWB.png)

This is the test button code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim testForm As fMainForm = New fMainForm()
    testForm.Show()
End Sub
```

I can't make heads or tails of what causes this behaviour. Does anyone have any idea of why this is happening?
I can offer more details if needed.

P.S. The main form is an MdiContainer and I have also checked the AllowMerge property for the menustrip, disabling it, but the result is still the same.

**Edit*
I just realised that I didn't post the main form's load event nor the login event and I apologize for the confusion it may have caused.
Here it is:**

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    currentOp = "Low Database"

    Try
        Dim taLogins As New RecipeMasterDBDataSetTableAdapters.LoginsTableAdapter
        Dim tLogins As New RecipeMasterDBDataSet.LoginsDataTable
        Dim PED As cPassEncrypterDecrypter
        PED = New cPassEncrypterDecrypter()

        If taLogins.FillByLoginAuthByUsernamePassword(tLogins, txtUsername.Text, PED.StringEncrypter(txtPassword.Text)) > 0 Then
            Dim taSessions As New RecipeMasterDBDataSetTableAdapters.SessionsTableAdapter
            Dim tSession As New RecipeMasterDBDataSet.SessionsDataTable
            taSessions.InsertQuerySession(Date.Now.Date & " " & Date.Now.Hour & ":" & Date.Now.Minute & ":" & Date.Now.Second, CInt(tLogins.Rows(0).Item(0)))

            fMainForm.CurrentUserSessionID = taSessions.SelectQueryCurrentSession(CInt(tLogins.Rows(0).Item(0)))
            If tLogins.Rows(0).Item(4) Then
                Dim taRecipes As New RecipeMasterDBDataSetTableAdapters.RecipesTableAdapter
                Dim tRecipes As New RecipeMasterDBDataSet.RecipesDataTable
                Dim taRatings As New RecipeMasterDBDataSetTableAdapters.RatingsTableAdapter

                taRecipes.Fill(tRecipes)
                taEvents.InsertQueryEvents("SELECT Statement - Login Interface", "Query: Generic query | Parameters - N/A" _
                                          , Date.Now, "Form: " & Me.Name & "Site: btnLogin_Click", _
                                          CInt(tLogins.Rows(0).Item(0)), 28)
                For recipeIndex As Integer = 0 To tRecipes.Rows.Count - 1
                    If My.Settings.ChosenLanguageIndex = 0 Then
                        taRatings.InsertQueryBaseRatingsForUser(Nothing, "Ainda não comentada", 0, 0D, False, "1900-01-01", CInt(tLogins.Rows(0).Item(0)), CInt(tRecipes.Rows(recipeIndex).Item(0)))
                        taEvents.InsertQueryEvents("INSERT Transaction - Login Interface", _
                                                  "Procedure: InsertQueryBaseRatingsForUser | Parameters - " & _
                                                  "Comment: " & String.Empty & " Comment_Flag: " & " Ainda não comentada " & _
                                                  "Rate_Level: " & 0 & " Rate_Score_Index: " & 0D & "Rated_Flag: " & _
                                                  "False " & "Rate_Recent_Date: " & "1900-01-01 " & "Login ID: " & _
                                                  CInt(tLogins.Rows(0).Item(0)) & " Recipe ID: " & _
                                                  CInt(tRecipes.Rows(recipeIndex).Item(0)), Date.Now, "Form: " & Me.Name & _
                                                  " Site: btnLogin_Click", CInt(tLogins.Rows(0).Item(0)), 31)
                    ElseIf My.Settings.ChosenLanguageIndex = 1 Then
                        taRatings.InsertQueryBaseRatingsForUser(Nothing, "Not yet commented", 0, 0D, False, "1900-01-01", CInt(tLogins.Rows(0).Item(0)), CInt(tRecipes.Rows(recipeIndex).Item(0)))
                        taEvents.InsertQueryEvents("INSERT Transaction - Login Interface", _
                                                  "Procedure: InsertQueryBaseRatingsForUser | Parameters - " & _
                                                  "Comment: " & String.Empty & " Comment_Flag: " & " Not yet commented " & _
                                                  "Rate_Level: " & 0 & " Rate_Score_Index: " & 0D & "Rated_Flag: " & _
                                                  "False " & "Rate_Recent_Date: " & "1900-01-01 " & "Login ID: " & _
                                                  CInt(tLogins.Rows(0).Item(0)) & " Recipe ID: " & _
                                                  CInt(tRecipes.Rows(recipeIndex).Item(0)), Date.Now, "Form: " & Me.Name & _
                                                  " Site: btnLogin_Click", CInt(tLogins.Rows(0).Item(0)), 31)
                    ElseIf My.Settings.ChosenLanguageIndex = 2 Then
                        taRatings.InsertQueryBaseRatingsForUser(Nothing, "Pas encore de commentaires", 0, 0D, False, "1900-01-01", CInt(tLogins.Rows(0).Item(0)), CInt(tRecipes.Rows(recipeIndex).Item(0)))
                        taEvents.InsertQueryEvents("INSERT Transaction - Login Interface", _
                                                  "Procedure: InsertQueryBaseRatingsForUser | Parameters - " & _
                                                  "Comment: " & String.Empty & " Comment_Flag: " & " Pas encore engagé " & _
                                                  "Rate_Level: " & 0 & " Rate_Score_Index: " & 0D & "Rated_Flag: " & _
                                                  "False " & "Rate_Recent_Date: " & "1900-01-01 " & "Login ID: " & _
                                                  CInt(tLogins.Rows(0).Item(0)) & " Recipe ID: " & _
                                                  CInt(tRecipes.Rows(recipeIndex).Item(0)), Date.Now, "Form: " & Me.Name & _
                                                  " Site: btnLogin_Click", CInt(tLogins.Rows(0).Item(0)), 31)
                    ElseIf My.Settings.ChosenLanguageIndex = 3 Then
                        taRatings.InsertQueryBaseRatingsForUser(Nothing, "Aún no ha comentado", 0, 0D, False, "1900-01-01", CInt(tLogins.Rows(0).Item(0)), CInt(tRecipes.Rows(recipeIndex).Item(0)))
                        taEvents.InsertQueryEvents("INSERT Transaction - Login Interface", _
                                                  "Procedure: InsertQueryBaseRatingsForUser | Parameters - " & _
                                                  "Comment: " & String.Empty & " Comment_Flag: " & " Aún no ha comentado " & _
                                                  "Rate_Level: " & 0 & " Rate_Score_Index: " & 0D & "Rated_Flag: " & _
                                                  "False " & "Rate_Recent_Date: " & "1900-01-01 " & "Login ID: " & _
                                                  CInt(tLogins.Rows(0).Item(0)) & " Recipe ID: " & _
                                                  CInt(tRecipes.Rows(recipeIndex).Item(0)), Date.Now, "Form: " & Me.Name & _
                                                  " Site: btnLogin_Click", CInt(tLogins.Rows(0).Item(0)), 31)
                    ElseIf My.Settings.ChosenLanguageIndex = 4 Then
                        taRatings.InsertQueryBaseRatingsForUser(Nothing, "Non ancora commentato", 0, 0D, False, "1900-01-01", CInt(tLogins.Rows(0).Item(0)), CInt(tRecipes.Rows(recipeIndex).Item(0)))
                        taEvents.InsertQueryEvents("INSERT Transaction - Login Interface", _
                                                  "Procedure: InsertQueryBaseRatingsForUser | Parameters - " & _
                                                  "Comment: " & String.Empty & " Comment_Flag: " & " Non ancora commentato " & _
                                                  "Rate_Level: " & 0 & " Rate_Score_Index: " & 0D & "Rated_Flag: " & _
                                                  "False " & "Rate_Recent_Date: " & "1900-01-01 " & "Login ID: " & _
                                                  CInt(tLogins.Rows(0).Item(0)) & " Recipe ID: " & _
                                                  CInt(tRecipes.Rows(recipeIndex).Item(0)), Date.Now, "Form: " & Me.Name & _
                                                  " Site: btnLogin_Click", CInt(tLogins.Rows(0).Item(0)), 31)
                    ElseIf My.Settings.ChosenLanguageIndex = 5 Then
                        taRatings.InsertQueryBaseRatingsForUser(Nothing, "Noch nicht kommentiert", 0, 0D, False, "1900-01-01", CInt(tLogins.Rows(0).Item(0)), CInt(tRecipes.Rows(recipeIndex).Item(0)))
                        taEvents.InsertQueryEvents("INSERT Transaction - Login Interface", _
                                                  "Procedure: InsertQueryBaseRatingsForUser | Parameters - " & _
                                                  "Comment: " & String.Empty & " Comment_Flag: " & " Noch nicht kommentiert " & _
                                                  "Rate_Level: " & 0 & " Rate_Score_Index: " & 0D & "Rated_Flag: " & _
                                                  "False " & "Rate_Recent_Date: " & "1900-01-01 " & "Login ID: " & _
                                                  CInt(tLogins.Rows(0).Item(0)) & " Recipe ID: " & _
                                                  CInt(tRecipes.Rows(recipeIndex).Item(0)), Date.Now, "Form: " & Me.Name & _
                                                  " Site: btnLogin_Click", CInt(tLogins.Rows(0).Item(0)), 31)
                    End If
                Next
                taLogins.UpdateQueryFirstLoginFlag(False, txtUsername.Text)
                taEvents.InsertQueryEvents("UPDATE Transaction - Login Interface", _
                                          "Procedure: UpdateQueryFirstLoginFlag | Parameters - " & _
                                          "IsFirstLogin: " & "False " & "Username: " & txtUsername.Text, Date.Now, _
                                          "Form: " & Me.Name & " Site: btnLogin_Click", CInt(tLogins.Rows(0).Item(0)), 31)
            End If

            fMainForm.ChefesToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
            fMainForm.ChefesToolStripMenuItem.Visible = True
            fMainForm.ReceitasToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
            fMainForm.ReceitasToolStripMenuItem.Visible = True
            fMainForm.AvaliaçõesToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
            fMainForm.AvaliaçõesToolStripMenuItem.Visible = True
            'fMainForm.GestõesMassivasToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
            'fMainForm.GestõesMassivasToolStripMenuItem.Visible = False
            fMainForm.ToolStripSeparator5.Visible = True
            fMainForm.AlterarDadosDaContaDeUtilizadorToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
            fMainForm.AlterarDadosDaContaDeUtilizadorToolStripMenuItem.Visible = True
            fMainForm.SuporteTécnicoToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
            fMainForm.SuporteTécnicoToolStripMenuItem.Visible = True
            'fMainForm.AdministraçãoToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
            'fMainForm.AdministraçãoToolStripMenuItem.Visible = False

            taLogins.UpdateQueryLastLoginTimeStamp(CDate(Date.Now), txtUsername.Text)
            taEvents.InsertQueryEvents("UPDATE Transaction - Login Interface", _
                                          "Procedure: UpdateQueryLastLoginTimeStamp | Parameters - " & _
                                          "LAST_LOGIN_TIMESTAMP: " & CDate(Date.Now) & " Username: " & txtUsername.Text, Date.Now, _
                                          "Form: " & Me.Name & " Site: btnLogin_Click", CInt(tLogins.Rows(0).Item(0)), 31)

            If CInt(tLogins.Rows(0).Item(7)) >= 1 And CInt(tLogins.Rows(0).Item(7)) <= 3 Then
                fMainForm.GestõesMassivasToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
                fMainForm.GestõesMassivasToolStripMenuItem.Visible = True
                fMainForm.AdministraçãoToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
                fMainForm.AdministraçãoToolStripMenuItem.Visible = True
                fMainForm.ToolStripSeparator2.Visible = True
                fMainForm.GerirFotografiasToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
                fMainForm.GerirFotografiasToolStripMenuItem.Visible = True
                fMainForm.ToolStripSeparator6.Visible = True
                fMainForm.FotografiasToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
                fMainForm.FotografiasToolStripMenuItem.Visible = True
                fMainForm.ToolStripSeparator9.Visible = True
                fMainForm.GeradorDeModelosToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
                fMainForm.GeradorDeModelosToolStripMenuItem.Visible = True
            ElseIf CInt(tLogins.Rows(0).Item(7)) >= 4 And CInt(tLogins.Rows(0).Item(7)) <= 5 Then
                fMainForm.GestõesMassivasToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
                fMainForm.GestõesMassivasToolStripMenuItem.Visible = True
                fMainForm.AdministraçãoToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
                fMainForm.AdministraçãoToolStripMenuItem.Visible = False
                fMainForm.ToolStripSeparator2.Visible = True
                fMainForm.GerirFotografiasToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
                fMainForm.GerirFotografiasToolStripMenuItem.Visible = True
                fMainForm.ToolStripSeparator6.Visible = True
                fMainForm.FotografiasToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
                fMainForm.FotografiasToolStripMenuItem.Visible = True
                fMainForm.ToolStripSeparator9.Visible = True
                fMainForm.GeradorDeModelosToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
                fMainForm.GeradorDeModelosToolStripMenuItem.Visible = True
            ElseIf CInt(tLogins.Rows(0).Item(7)) = 6 Then
                fMainForm.GestõesMassivasToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
                fMainForm.GestõesMassivasToolStripMenuItem.Visible = False
                fMainForm.AdministraçãoToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
                fMainForm.AdministraçãoToolStripMenuItem.Visible = False
                fMainForm.ToolStripSeparator2.Visible = True
                fMainForm.GerirFotografiasToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
                fMainForm.GerirFotografiasToolStripMenuItem.Visible = True
                fMainForm.ToolStripSeparator6.Visible = False
                fMainForm.FotografiasToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
                fMainForm.FotografiasToolStripMenuItem.Visible = False
                fMainForm.ToolStripSeparator9.Visible = False
                fMainForm.GeradorDeModelosToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
                fMainForm.GeradorDeModelosToolStripMenuItem.Visible = False
            Else
                fMainForm.GestõesMassivasToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
                fMainForm.GestõesMassivasToolStripMenuItem.Visible = False
                fMainForm.AdministraçãoToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
                fMainForm.AdministraçãoToolStripMenuItem.Visible = False
                fMainForm.ToolStripSeparator2.Visible = False
                fMainForm.GerirFotografiasToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
                fMainForm.GerirFotografiasToolStripMenuItem.Visible = False
                fMainForm.ToolStripSeparator6.Visible = False
                fMainForm.FotografiasToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
                fMainForm.FotografiasToolStripMenuItem.Visible = False
                fMainForm.ToolStripSeparator9.Visible = False
                fMainForm.GeradorDeModelosToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
                fMainForm.GeradorDeModelosToolStripMenuItem.Visible = False
            End If

            fMainForm.CurrentUser = CStr(tLogins.Rows(0).Item(1))
            AuthSessionValid = True
            Me.Close()
        Else
            numberOfLoginFailedAttempts += 1
            If My.Settings.ChosenLanguageIndex = 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("As credenciais que introduziu estão incorrectas." & ControlChars.CrLf & "Por favor, tente novamente." _
                            , "Erro: Credenciais Inválidas", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            ElseIf My.Settings.ChosenLanguageIndex = 1 Then
                MessageBox.Show("The credentials you entered are incorrect." & ControlChars.CrLf & "Please, try again." _
                            , "Error: Invalid Credentials", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            ElseIf My.Settings.ChosenLanguageIndex = 2 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Les informations d'identification que vous avez inscrits sont incorrects." & ControlChars.CrLf & "Veuillez réessayer." _
                            , "Erreur: Lettres de Créance non Valides", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            ElseIf My.Settings.ChosenLanguageIndex = 3 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Las credenciales que ha introducido son incorrectos." & ControlChars.CrLf & "Por favor, inténtelo de nuevo." _
                            , "Error: Credenciales no Válidas", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            ElseIf My.Settings.ChosenLanguageIndex = 4 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Le credenziali immesse non sono corrette." & ControlChars.CrLf & "Si prega, riprovare." _
                            , "Errore: Credenziali non Valide", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            ElseIf My.Settings.ChosenLanguageIndex = 5 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Die Anmeldeinformationen eingegeben sind falsch." & ControlChars.CrLf & "Bitte versuche es erneut." _
                            , "Fehler: Ungültige Anmeldeinformationen ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End If

            If numberOfLoginFailedAttempts > 5 Then
                btnLogin.Enabled = False
                If My.Settings.ChosenLanguageIndex = 0 Then
                    Throw New Exception("O início de sessão foi bloqueado durante 30 segundos, devido ao número abusivo de tentativas." & ControlChars.CrLf & "Por favor, aguarde...")
                ElseIf My.Settings.ChosenLanguageIndex = 1 Then
                    Throw New Exception("Session start was blocked for 30 seconds due to abusive attempts." & ControlChars.CrLf & "Please wait...")
                ElseIf My.Settings.ChosenLanguageIndex = 2 Then
                    Throw New Exception("Le démarrage de la session a été bloqué pendant 30 secondes en raison de tentatives abusives." & ControlChars.CrLf & "S'il vous plaît, attendez...")
                ElseIf My.Settings.ChosenLanguageIndex = 3 Then
                    Throw New Exception("El inicio de sesión se bloqueó durante 30 segundos debido a intentos abusivos." & ControlChars.CrLf & "Por favor, espere...")
                ElseIf My.Settings.ChosenLanguageIndex = 4 Then
                    Throw New Exception("Inizia di la sessione è stata bloccata per 30 secondi a causa di tentativi abusivi." & ControlChars.CrLf & "Attendere prego...")
                ElseIf My.Settings.ChosenLanguageIndex = 5 Then
                    Throw New Exception("Der Sitzungsstart wurde wegen missbräuchlicher, Versuche für 30 Sekunden blockiert." & ControlChars.CrLf & "Warten Sie mal...")
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim taLogins As New RecipeMasterDBDataSetTableAdapters.LoginsTableAdapter
        Dim tLogins As New RecipeMasterDBDataSet.LoginsDataTable
        Dim taEvents As New RecipeMasterDBDataSetTableAdapters.AppEventsTableAdapter
        Dim tEvents As New RecipeMasterDBDataSet.LoginsDataTable

        taLogins.FillByLoginByUsername(tLogins, "Admin")
        taEvents.InsertQueryEvents(currentOp & " Error - Multiple Failed Login Attempts", "Code Error: " & ex.HResult & " | Error Description: " & ex.Message & " | Source: " & _
        ex.Source, Date.Now, "Site: " & ex.TargetSite.Name, CInt(tLogins.Rows(0).Item(0)), 10)

        If My.Settings.ChosenLanguageIndex = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Ocorreu a seguinte excepção:" & ControlChars.CrLf & ex.Message & ControlChars.CrLf & ControlChars.CrLf & _
            "Rastreamento de Pilha: " & ex.StackTrace, "Erro de Sistema: " & ex.HResult, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        ElseIf My.Settings.ChosenLanguageIndex = 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("The following exception occurred:" & ControlChars.CrLf & ex.Message & ControlChars.CrLf & ControlChars.CrLf & _
            "Stack Trace: " & ex.StackTrace, "System Error: " & ex.HResult, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        ElseIf My.Settings.ChosenLanguageIndex = 2 Then
            MessageBox.Show("L'exception suivante s'est produite:" & ControlChars.CrLf & ex.Message & ControlChars.CrLf & ControlChars.CrLf & _
            "Trace de la Pile: " & ex.StackTrace, "Erreur de Système: " & ex.HResult, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        ElseIf My.Settings.ChosenLanguageIndex = 3 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Se produjo la siguiente excepción:" & ControlChars.CrLf & ex.Message & ControlChars.CrLf & ControlChars.CrLf & _
            "Rastro de la Pila: " & ex.StackTrace, "Error del Sistema: " & ex.HResult, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        ElseIf My.Settings.ChosenLanguageIndex = 4 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Si è verificato il seguente eccezione:" & ControlChars.CrLf & ex.Message & ControlChars.CrLf & ControlChars.CrLf & _
            "Analisi dello Stack: " & ex.StackTrace, "Errore di Sistema: " & ex.HResult, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        ElseIf My.Settings.ChosenLanguageIndex = 5 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Die folgende Ausnahme ist aufgetreten:" & ControlChars.CrLf & ex.Message & ControlChars.CrLf & ControlChars.CrLf & _
            "Stapelüberwachung: " & ex.StackTrace, "Systemfehler: " & ex.HResult, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        End If
        tmrFailedLoginAttemptsController.Start()
    End Try
End Sub
```

**Here's the main form's load event:**

```
Private Sub fMainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        LastVisitedForm = Me.Text

        currentOp = "High System"

        If Not Directory.Exists(My.Settings.BackupFilesFolderPath) Then
            Throw New Exception("The backup files folder either was moved or is missing from this computer." & ControlChars.CrLf & _
        "Check your application folders for any misspeled names.")
            Application.Exit()
        End If

        If Not Directory.Exists(My.Settings.DBPath) Then
            Throw New Exception("The database files folder either was moved or is missing from this computer." & ControlChars.CrLf & _
    "Check your application folders for any misspeled names.")
            Application.Exit()
        End If

        If My.Settings.BackupFilesFolderPath = String.Empty Then
            My.Settings.BackupFilesFolderPath = 
Application.StartupPath.Remove(Application.StartupPath.Length - 10) & "\Backup Files"
            My.Settings.Save()
        End If

        If My.Settings.DBPath = String.Empty Then
            My.Settings.DBPath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA" 'temp folder
            My.Settings.Save()
        End If

        If My.Settings.DBFileName = String.Empty Then
            My.Settings.DBFileName = "RecipeMasterDB.mdf"
            My.Settings.Save()
        End If

        Me.Text = "Recipe Master"

        JanelasToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False

        EmailAccountCheckSumArray = New List(Of String)

        'System clock code...

        'Synchronize time always on application startup

        secondsController = CDate(My.Settings.AppCurTime).Second
        minutesController = CDate(My.Settings.AppCurTime).Minute
        hoursController = CDate(My.Settings.AppCurTime).Hour
        daysController = CDate(My.Settings.AppCurTime).Day
        monthsController = CDate(My.Settings.AppCurTime).Month
        yearsController = CDate(My.Settings.AppCurTime).Year

        SystemClockStartUp = True
        tmrAppTimeController.Start()

        LanguageInterpreter(My.Settings.ChosenLanguageIndex)

        ChefesToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
        ChefesToolStripMenuItem.Visible = False
        ReceitasToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
        ReceitasToolStripMenuItem.Visible = False
        AvaliaçõesToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
        AvaliaçõesToolStripMenuItem.Visible = False
        GestõesMassivasToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
        GestõesMassivasToolStripMenuItem.Visible = False
        ToolStripSeparator5.Visible = False
        AlterarDadosDaContaDeUtilizadorToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
        AlterarDadosDaContaDeUtilizadorToolStripMenuItem.Visible = False
        SuporteTécnicoToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
        SuporteTécnicoToolStripMenuItem.Visible = False
        AdministraçãoToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
        AdministraçãoToolStripMenuItem.Visible = False
    Catch ex As Exception
        'exception handling code ...
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you need a ghost form? You can check the FirstRun in your MainForm's load event and show the setting form as dialog.

Comment: Well, I did point out why I need it, but I'll clarify as best as I can.
When it's the first time running the application, a form will pop up for the user (admin) to set up some settings for the application.
When it's not the first time running the application, then the main form pops up.

I tried the ghost form approach, because trying the approach where you should change the startup form of the project with main sub didn't seem to work.

Comment: You did explain why you _think_ you need it, but like Han I can't see any reason to use a whole hidden form just to check the value of a variable and then display a different form.

Comment: You can't expect anybody to find a bug in the code from a screenshot.  It is a bad idea anyway, you are giving the user a *very* hard to complete task before he can get familiar with the app.  He is quite likely to fumble it and then gets hopelessly stuck because FirstRun is now False without any way to reset it.  You can't even provide assistance when he calls you, that user.config file is near impossible to find back.  Belongs in an Options menu item or an app.config file that's edited by an admin.

Comment: The user will have assistance on the form itself...
Also, we're getting off the problem at hand here. I just need to know why the toolstripitems are having such behaviour...
As I said, anything else that is need for me to share to solve this I'll share, I just don't know what else to share but what I already did...
I posted the main form's load event and the menustrip as well as the toolstripitems were painted from the designer, therefor the code was auto-generated.
I also posted what the test button does and the screenshots show the scenario.
What else can I post?

Comment: @ADyson Ok... let's put it this way.
I want the user to see form A on first run. User sets the variables for first run.
After the application had its first run, when the user runs it again then form B shows up.
If I don't have a form that's hidden for that variable, how can I do it (appart from the main sub I mentioned before)?
I can't write the code on form B, otherwise that'll always be the startup form.

Comment: Can you show the code after the user logs in where you try to make the extra ToolStripItems visible?

Comment: I apologize as I'm at fault...
I didn't realise that I didn't share the form load's event of the main form. I will post that up right away as well as the login event.

Comment: You could just write the code in your Main method, before you call Application.Run(). You can check the value of your firstRun variable, and use it to decide which form to display (A or B). If that didn't work for you it would be better to show that code and get it fixed, because that's the obvious solution

Comment: I tried the main sub approach by disabling the application framework on the project and selecting the Sub Main as the startup object.
Then I wrote the exact same code for the Sub (the code that is displayed here on the fGhostForm_FormClosed event).
The behaviour of the toolstripitems is the same as with the Ghost Form approach.
Therefor, I guess that if I find out why this is happening and solve it, I might go back into using the main sub approach.

Comment: For me i would use the registry on setup and store a value there, it will check for me if he's new or not, on setup make it 0, first run, show settings form, set value to 1, next run it's already 1 main form will show..

Comment: @Devcon I thought about going that way, but it's not possible in my case, because on the application there's an option that allows users with a certain access level (such as the admin) to be able to restore the application's settings to default and that point I'll have no way of checking if it's first time the application is being run or not. To put it simple, everytime the application is restored to default settings, the FirstRun flag will be updated to true.

Comment: @Simbiose what problem will you face if you make the settings form your first form to load? ok how about you launch the settings form first and on load check if it's firstUse, if true keep it, if not close and launch main form, that's how you delete your ghost form. And you can keep the my.settings but make sure you create an installer (a setup) or else when he changes the app's location the settings file will be renewed.

Comment: and consider creating cases when you have something like this, or subs/functions to call to prevent repetitions

Comment: @Devcon That's a perspective I didn't think of. I'll go for that instead, thank you.
However, this still doesn't solve my current problem.

Comment: it might because you said the toolstripitems show up based on which form you set as first form to load, you can try it and we'll see what happens

Comment: In the `Private Sub btnLogin_Click` method,  there is this statement `fMainForm.ChefesToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True` and several others that set `fMainForm` parented features.  However, we do not see where `fMainForm` is declared.  When you hover the mouse cursor over `fMainForm`, does it show "Property My.My.MyProject.MyForms.fMainForm as fMainForm"?  If so, that is the source of your problem as that is the infernal default instance and you later create a new `fMainForm` and display that.

Comment: @TnTinMn Oh God...
Yep, this is indeed the reason behind the current behaviour.
I just needed to change the chain of command from the main form to the ghost form.
It appears that everything is working as it should be.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to TnTinMn, the answer lied in simply instantiating the main form on the Ghost Form, while declaring the variable as public shared variable.
Then all that was required was to call the menustripitems through that variable.

**Code for load event of Ghost Form:**

```
Public Class fGhostForm

    Public Shared MainForm As fMainForm

    Private Sub fGhostForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub fGhostForm_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosed
        If My.Settings.FirstRun Then
            Dim FormToLaunch As fFirstRunApplicationSettings = New fFirstRunApplicationSettings()
            FormToLaunch.ShowDialog()
        Else
            MainForm = New fMainForm()
            MainForm.ShowDialog()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Code to call and control the menustripitems:**

```
fGhostForm.MainForm.ChefesToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
fGhostForm.MainForm.ChefesToolStripMenuItem.Visible = True
```

Thanks everyone for their time.